# disassembler in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, disassembly

I'm working on a project, and on a machine without Xcode, I'm getting a crash. (of course it works on my machine B-/) I have a crash log, with a PC offset for the crash. I'd like to be able to see where that actually is in the code. I know that Code Warrior can disassemble the code (presumably, only debugable code) and show it interspersed with the C code, then I just have to look for that address, and I'm done.

Is there an easy way to do this in Xcode?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things in Xcode you may want to look at.  The first would be to select your source code file and choose Build->Show Assembly Code. What this *won't* give you though is offsets.

The second assembly capability is in the debugger. Choose Run->Debugger Display->Source and Disassembly, and the debugger will show you both source and assembly code side-by-side. However, the two are *not* interspersed.

If neither of these Xcode facilities give you what you need, your only recourse may be the [otool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) command line tool.

I've never found a way to generate or view source and assembly interspersed.